# PhpStorm nodemon debug - don't stop on breakpoints

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, webstorm, breakpoints, nodemon

I work on a PhpStorm (2019.3 if it makes sense) and use nodemon for debugging my Node.js project.

What do I do to launch nodemon with debugger?

An npm script: 
`"serve-debug": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon --inspect dist/bot.js"`

It did work properly on PhpStorm 2019.2, but doesn't in current version.
Debugger gets attached successfully, but doesn't stop on any breakpoints.

I checked out the [tutorial](https://samkirkiles.svbtle.com/webstorm-node-js-debugging-with-nodemon) and found one where the solution gets resolved. It suggests to add a config for node.js remote debugging. The problem is - I don't have this option in my dropdown list of config templates.

Does anyone have any idea of what the possible solution could be?

Answer (score 0):

Must be related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42932;
Note that the officially supported way to debug applications started with nodemon is using [Attach to a Node.js/Chrome](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.3/run-debug-configuration-node-js-remote-debug.html) debug configuration - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.2/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#nodemon:

- start your app with `npm run serve-debug`
- create an *Attach to a Node.js/Chrome* debug configuration with Port set to 9229, debug

I'd also suggest changing the option in your script from `--inspect` to `--inspect=brk` to make sure that the execution is suspended until the debugger is attached

Comment: Sorry, I might be doing something wrong. Corrected my script option to --inspect-brk and added an attachment tot nodejs, but phpstorm still doesn't stop on breakpoints.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing a sample project the issue can be reproduced with